# How do I save a dynamically generated XML document to a database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I can't seem to figure out how to save an XML file that I generated with the DOM objects to my database..

Here is my PHP:

```
$xmlraw = $doc->saveXML();

$xmlQuery=sprintf("INSERT INTO xmlTestTable (XMLString) VALUES ('%s')", $xmlraw); 

$result = mysql_query($xmlQuery);
```

I also tried:

```
$xmlQuery=sprintf("INSERT INTO xmlTestTable (XMLString) VALUES ('%s')", $doc->saveXML()); 

$result = mysql_query($xmlQuery);
```

Where `$doc` is the XML Document I created.

I am able to see the XML output in my browser when I do this:

```
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

There are no errors being outputted or anything...

My MySQL Column that this is being injected into is 'Long Text'

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to get the XML string, using, as you guessed, the **`saveXML()`** method :

```
$xmlraw = $doc->saveXML();
```

Then, you need to insert this value ; but you must **escape it** properly !

Escaping a string to inject it into an SQL query is something you'll do using the specific function that's provided by the API you're using to connect to your database -- as you are using `mysql_*` functions, you'll use [**`mysql_real_escape_string()`**](http://fr.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

```
$escapedString = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlraw);
```

Now, you have the string you can inject into your SQL query :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO xmlTestTable (XMLString) VALUES ('$escapedString')";
```

You can also use sprintf, like you did, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Please escape the xml with `mysql_real_escape_string` - this will fix your problem, and it will save you from sql injection attacks.